# How can I search a Laravel collection using WHERE LIKE (or equivalent)

Tags: php, laravel, search, collections, builder

I have an equipment bookings register/calendar system that I am currently working on using Laravel.

Equipment can be booked out directly to staff as needed or scheduled for future dates.

For example Laptop 1 might have three bookings but the laptop can only be booked out to one person at a time.

The system is up and running and the user can search for current/scheduled bookings.

But I am having trouble allowing the user to search for the staff name as I need to split the query up.

As you can see I am first getting  all of the devices from lines 7-14.

Then I am appending all of the bookings from each device to the `$bookings` collection in a new key called “available bookings”.

I am wondering how I can search the available bookings key for the staff_name field as I have already returned the eloquent queries as collections.

```
public function searchCurrentBookings(Request $request) {
      
        // Making sure the user entered a keyword.
        if ($request->has('query')) {

           //Get all devices
            $bookings = devices::where('device_status', '!=', 'decommisioned')
                ->where(function ($query) {
                $query->Where('devices.device_id', 'like', '%' . request('query') . '%')
                      ->orWhere('device_serial', 'like', '%' . request('query') . '%')
                      ->orWhere('model_name_fk', 'like', '%' . request('query') . '%')
                      ->orWhere('device_status', 'like', '%' . request('query') . '%'); 
                 })
             ->get();

                //Append all of the bookings for each device to collection
                foreach($bookings as $booking) {
                    $booking->available_bookings = bookings::leftJoin('staff','staff.staff_id','bookings.checked_out_to')
                        ->where('device_id', '=',$booking->device_id)
                        ->WhereIn('bookings.status', ['scheduled', 'checked_out'])
                }

                //How can I search the available bookings in this collection?
                $collection = $bookings->available_bookings->Where('staff_name', 'like', '%' . request('query') . '%')
            
            // If there are results return them, if none, return the error message.
            return $bookings->count() ? $bookings : $error;
        }
    }
```

Here is an example of the **$bookings** object

```
[
  {
    "device_id": "Laptop 1",
    "device_serial": "63YNERQN",
    "model_name_fk": "Dell Latitude 3310",
    "device_status": "unavailable",
    "available_bookings": [
      {
        "id": 45,
        "device_id": "Laptop 1",
        "date_from": "1-May-2021",
        "date_to": "5-May-2021",
        "status": "checked_out",
        "checked_out_to": 1,
        "updated_at": "2021-05-27T11:52:13.000000Z",
        "staff_id": 1,
        "staff_name": "Jaden Bird"
      },
      {
        "id": 46,
        "device_id": "Laptop 1",
        "date_from": "6-May-2021",
        "date_to": "8-May-2021",
        "status": "scheduled",
        "checked_out_to": 2,
        "updated_at": "2021-05-27T11:52:13.000000Z",
        "staff_id": 2,
        "staff_name": "Lilo Berry"
      },
      {
        "id": 47,
        "device_id": "Laptop 1",
        "date_from": "17-May-2021",
        "date_to": "27-May-2021",
        "status": "scheduled",
        "checked_out_to": 4,
        "updated_at": "2021-05-27T11:52:13.000000Z",
        "staff_id": 4,
        "staff_name": "Barbora Forester"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "device_id": "Laptop 3",
    "device_serial": "PNX9N8R8",
    "model_name_fk": "Dell Latitude 7490",
    "device_status": "unavailable",
    "available_bookings": [
      {
        "id": 48,
        "device_id": "Laptop 3",
        "date_from": "5-May-2021",
        "date_to": "8-May-2021",
        "status": "checked_out",
        "checked_out_to": 3,
        "updated_at": "2021-05-27T11:52:13.000000Z",
        "staff_id": 3,
        "staff_name": "Kaiden Ojeda"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "device_id": "Laptop 4",
    "device_serial": "GTUEDDDH",
    "model_name_fk": "Dell Latitude 5300",
    "device_status": "available",
    "available_bookings": [
      {
        "id": 50,
        "device_id": "Laptop 4",
        "date_from": "30-May-2021",
        "date_to": "30-May-2021",
        "status": "scheduled",
        "checked_out_to": 6,
        "updated_at": "2021-05-27T11:52:13.000000Z",
        "staff_id": 6,
        "staff_name": "Luka Evans"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "device_id": "Projector",
    "device_serial": "Projector",
    "model_name_fk": "Epson EH-TW550",
    "device_status": "available",
    "available_bookings": []
  }
]
```

Example image of the system below.
I would like to search for staff name on all bookings or just the active booking (whichever is easier).
[image: Bookings Calendar Example]

DB Structure below:
[image: DB Structure]

Models:

Devices:

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Devices extends Model
{
    #use HasFactory;

    protected $table = 'devices';
    /**
     * @var string $primaryKey Name of the primary key
     */
    protected $primaryKey = 'device_id';
    /**
     * @var bool $incrementing The PK does not increment
     */
    public $incrementing = false;
    /**
     * @var string $keyType Primary key is a string (i.e. not an integer)
     */
    protected $keyType = 'string';
    /**
     * @var array $fillable The attributes that are mass assignable.
     */
    protected $fillable = [
        'device_id',
        'device_serial',
        'model_name_fk',
        'device_status'
    ];

    public function bookings() {
        $this->hasMany(Bookings::class, 'device_id', 'device_id');
      }
}
```

Bookings:

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Bookings extends Model
{
 #use HasFactory;

 protected $table = 'bookings';
 /**
  * @var string $primaryKey Name of the primary key
  */
 protected $primaryKey = 'id';
 /**
  * @var bool $incrementing The PK does not increment
  */
 public $incrementing = true;
 /**
  * @var string $keyType Primary key is a string (i.e. not an integer)
  */
 protected $keyType = 'integer';
 /**
  * @var array $fillable The attributes that are mass assignable.
  */
 protected $fillable = [
     'device_id',
     'date_from',
     'date_to',
     'status',
     'checked_out_to'
 ];
    public function staff() {
        $this->belongsTo(Staff::class, 'checked_out_to', 'staff_id');
      }
}
```

Staff:

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Staff extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'staff';
    /**
     * @var string $primaryKey Name of the primary key
     */
    protected $primaryKey = 'staff_id';
    /**
     * @var bool $incrementing The PK does not increment
     */
    public $incrementing = true;
    /**
     * @var string $keyType Primary key is a string (i.e. not an integer)
     */
    protected $keyType = 'integer';
    /**
     * @var array $fillable The attributes that are mass assignable.
     */
    protected $fillable = [
        'staff_id',
        'staff_name'
    ];
}
```

Comment: Can you please share your Booking eloquent model class for further understanding,

Comment: @JibinBose Hi Jibin - My Bookings model is the default model with no changes and the devices model has only primary key set to device_id and no incrementing as my pk for devices is a string (device_id is PK). So I'm not sure how helpful sharing it would be. I have put an image in my original post of my db structure though if that helps at all. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hopefully, this might help you out.

In your Device model class file add relation.

```
public function bookings() {
  return $this->hasMany(Booking::class, 'device_id', 'device_id');
}
```

In your Booking model class file add relation.

```
public function staff() {
  return $this->belongsTo(Staff::class, 'checked_out_to', 'staff_id');
}
```

Now in your controller file, you can filter the relation data using the below.

```
$search = $request->search_name;
$bookings = Device::with('bookings', 'bookings.staff')->whereHas('bookings.staff', function($q) use($search) {
                return $q->where('staff_name', 'like', '%' . $search .'%');
        })->get();
```

Add all other query conditions that you need on the Booking table before you call the `get()` function.

*Note: I Hope I got the table relations correct. If not please correct it as per your mappings.*

---

*Edit: I forgot to add return statements to the model relation functions. I have updated the same in my answer.*

Comment: Thanks for this, unfortuantly I'm having some errors.
With hasWhere I receive - Call to a member function getRelationExistenceQuery() on null.
If I change whereHas to just Where alone I receive Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'bookings.staff' in 'where clause' (SQL: select * from `devices` where `bookings`.`staff` = (select * where `staff_name` like %Jaden%)).
I do need to read up on elloquent relations more, so maybe I am missing something simple.
I've added all my models in my original post (with changes) if it's helpful. I feel like it must be something simple I'm missing. Thanks

Comment: Hi, sorry it's working now! :) You're a legend! I just needed return keyword in each model function. I should read up more on elloquent relations as I think it could improve other aspects of my app. Thanks so much for your help!

Comment: @masterg174 Sorry for missing the return keyword. Happy to help. Keep learning.